# Passing a header value to a get request in django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to pass a value through the Headers of a get request.

Im trying the below but it doesn't work,

```
class ListCategoriesView(generics.ListAPIView):
"""
Provides a get method handler.
"""
serializer_class = CategorySerializer

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    token = request.data.get("token", "")
    if not token:
      """ 
          do some action here
      """
    if not UserAccess.objects.filter(accessToken=token).exists():
      """ 
          do some action here
      """
    else:
      """ 
          do some action here
      """
```

I want to pass the token in the headers like that :

[image]

can anyone help me with this issue,
thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You said it yourself, you're passing it in the headers, so you need to get it from there. DRF does not do anything special to access the headers, so it proxies to the underlying Django HttpRequest object, which makes them available via the [`META` attribute](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META), converted to uppercase and prefixed by `HTTP_`:

```
token = request.META.get("HTTP_TOKEN", "")
```